# How can I generate a UML diagram without a GUI

Tags: uml

I'm trying to create a UML diagram from the command line without preexisting code.

Eventually I'll write code in C++/Java, but I need to create a diagram first.

I'm thinking of a header-like file, which could be read and could generate a diagram.

Of course, I could just create a header and generate it. However, I'm not supposed to write any code until I've submitted my diagram (I'd also just like to have an efficient way to do this for the future).

Comment: Look into PlantUML. Works without GUI.

Comment: @ThomasKilian would you mind if I include this proposal into my answer as well? I'm not familiar with PlantUML and as I mentioned I try to keep the core of the answer detached from specific tools but I provide already one solution in the end. Adding your suggestion would make it more complete.

Comment: @Ister Sure. Go ahead :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UML does not require application to draw. On the contrary one of the main usages of UML is to model the application that you're going to build to understand it better and make a better code as a result.

You also don't use application you create to draw UML diagram. You can use any application that supports UML modelling. Simple Google search or visit on Wikipedia will give you tons of options. You may even take a sheet of paper and a pencil. I've seen a course of UML, where participants did not use computers. They were supposed to learn UML, not tools that allow to draw it.

Finally (answering the question stated in the question topic), UML is in no way limited to model only graphical applications. Static structure and dynamic behaviour of the system exists regardless if user communicates with it through a GUI or command line.

Are you sure you understood the reason why you are supposed to make a UML diagram or do you disagree with that reason? What I can definitely suggest is to find a good book about IT business analysis using UML. This site is not to recommend specific books, but again Google will be your friend here.

---

As according to the comment the goal is to actually generate a UML class diagram from text let me add a second part of answer

First disclaimer. In general SO is not a place to ask for tools and that question is brushing it. Let me make my answer more generic though.

UML is in general graphical language so technically what you need is something that will parse text version of your "diagram" into a nice picture.

Most if not all tools keep UML in some textual format, be it XMI or some internal legacy solution. The problem with that is that the format is usually pretty complex.

There are some tools that are intended to "draw" diagram by typing text and that's probably something that would suit you best. In general I definitely prefer "normal" GUI but if you insist yuml.me has a nice and easy to understand textual layer based on which it generates really cool diagrams. You may expect you will find others as well, so as usually, ask uncle Google. As suggested by Thomas Kilian in a comment, PlantUML is another example as it can work without GUI and "is an open-source tool allowing users to create UML diagrams from a plain text language." (quote after [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlantUML))

Comment: I was going to comment "something" until I got to your last paragraph. That's what I intended to say xD

Comment: Please do not accuse a new contributor of something you can't be sure of. A better way to put it would have been something like "Are you sure you understood the reason why you are supposed to make a UML diagram or do you disagree with that reason?"

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl , agreed. I have changed the last paragraph accordingly. Even though I suppose my guess was correct ;-)

Comment: I'm aware that creating UML isn't dependent on any pre-existing program. What I meant was, I want to generate a UML graphic through the cli just by specifying a each classname, and how they inherit/implement each other. Sorry if I didn't make this clear in my original post. TLDR Rephrasing: How can I create a UML >>>graphic<<< without touching a gui?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I'll try to avoid asking for software recommendations in the future :)